# Facebook Like on list of newsitems with correct og:image

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

`og:image` is page-specific.

When I have a list of newsitems (like 10 newsitems with 10 small pictures ) and I want to like 1 newsitem on that list (you can like every item), then the standard facebook like code works fine .. but.. in my knowlegde you can only set one page specific og:image and not use multiple og:image on one page or pass (through the normal FB like functions) the right og:image

How can I get this right? So that on one overview page with 10 items and 10 images i like the 1 item and the corresponding right image is figured in FB?

You can only set 1 og:image on a page, but I have 10 items on a page with 10 different pictures.

Answer (score 0):

For the URL for each of the items, you can include a different query string parameter.  And on the page itself, depending on the query string parameter, you can specify a different value for og:image.  This will need to be done server side because Facebook's bot that scrapes the page will not recognize if the value is changed by JavaScript on the client.